# how to update the value frequently on same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading data everyday from a text file.

Here I have discussed two loops which defines for monday and tuesday. If I start the program on monday, I can get the data and updated in dataframe and when the day is moved to tuesday to friday I can get all the days information to single dataframe.

Let me assume that monday is 4th feb and friday is 8th feb.

Again, when I am running the program on 11th feb(monday), the the updated value should be saved in the monday dataframe only. How to do that?

```
newDF = pd.DataFrame()
new1=pd.DataFrame()
a=time.ctime()
b=a.split(" ")
print(a)
with open("call_1_feb.txt","r")as f:
    file=f.readlines()

if b[0]=="Mon":
        #print(b[1])
        Bcount,BPcount,BFcount,BOcount=0,0,0,0
        Scount,SPcount,SFcount,SOcount=0,0,0,0         
        for j in range(len(file)):
            if re.search("WIN",file[j]):
                Bcount+=1
                if re.search("\+\+",file[j]):
                    BPcount+=1   
                if re.search("--",file[j]):
                    BFcount+=1     
                if not re.search("\+\+",file[j]):
                    if not re.search("--",file[j]):
                        BOcount+=1

            if re.search("LOST",file[j]):
                Scount+=1
                if re.search("\+\+",file[j]):
                    SPcount+=1   
                if re.search("--",file[j]):
                    SFcount+=1   
                if not re.search("\+\+",file[j]):
                    if not re.search("--",file[j]):
                        SOcount+=1
        Date=b[0]+"["+b[1]+"-"+b[3]+"-"+b[5]+"]"
        #print(Date)
        T1=[Date,BPcount,BFcount,BOcount,Bcount,SPcount,SFcount,SOcount,Scount]
        df=pd.DataFrame(np.array(T1).reshape(-1,len(T1)))
        df=df.loc[0:]
        print(df)
        df.to_csv("output.csv")

if b[0]=="Tue":
            Bcount,BPcount,BFcount,BOcount=0,0,0,0
            Scount,SPcount,SFcount,SOcount=0,0,0,0         
            for j in range(len(file)):
                if re.search("BUY",file[j]):
                    Bcount+=1
                    if re.search("\+\+",file[j]):
                        BPcount+=1   
                    if re.search("--",file[j]):
                        BFcount+=1     
                    if not re.search("\+\+",file[j]):
                        if not re.search("--",file[j]):
                            BOcount+=1

                if re.search("SELL",file[j]):
                    Scount+=1
                    if re.search("\+\+",file[j]):
                        SPcount+=1   
                    if re.search("--",file[j]):
                        SFcount+=1   
                    if not re.search("\+\+",file[j]):
                        if not re.search("--",file[j]):
                            SOcount+=1
            Date1=b[0]+"["+b[1]+"-"+b[3]+"-"+b[5]+"]"
            T2=[Date1,BPcount,BFcount,BOcount,Bcount,SPcount,SFcount,SOcount,Scount]
            df1=pd.DataFrame(np.array(T2).reshape(-1,len(T2)))
            df1=df1.loc[0:]            
            new1 = new1.append(df, ignore_index = True)
            new1=new1.append(df1,ignore_index=True)
            print(new1)
            new1.to_csv("output.csv")
```

input file would be:

> ++INDIA WIN@769.6
>   --UAE  WIN@1143.95
>   ++SRILANKA LOST@325.4
>   BANGLADESH  WIN@19316.199`
>   ++SCOTLAND WIN@160.8
>   AUSTRALIA      LOST@451.85
>   USA    WIN@2791.25
>   --UK   LOST@661.85
>   KENYA WIN@942.75
>   --PAKISTAN    LOST@1043.85,